# Collecting hotels.com rewards points for a third-party booking

Tags: online-resources, hotels, loyalty-programs

I'll be staying in a hotel in NYC next week, and the reservation was made by a third party via hotels.com.  The email confirmation, which they forwarded to me, included this little snippet:

[image]

I already have a hotels.com account, and have been collecting rewards toward a free night for a while.  Is there any way to add this hotels.com reservation to my existing account or otherwise take advantage of these two nights reward credit?

Comment: If they had a hotels.com account, then they'd be the ones to get the credit for those nights. Unlike many hotel chain loyalty programs, the hotels.com one rewards the person making the booking not the person staying in the room

Comment: @Gagravarr: I would expect so, too, but clearly they have not done so.  It's a small company, they probably don't think about such things :)

Answer (score 3):

I found my own answer shortly after posting.  Although it's not immediately obvious how to do it, instructions are available from hotels.com [customer service](http://customercare.hotels.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14342):

1. Sign in to your Hotels.com account, go to Find bookings, fill out the form and Submit.
2. Select View your reservation.
3. Scroll to the Hotels.com™ Rewards box and select Sign in and attach this booking to your account. If you don't see this link, your booking is already attached to your account.
   [image]
4. You should then see this message: "Success! You have successfully added this booking to your Hotels.com™ Rewards account."